# Avoid buffering when shuffling data

Tags: python, numpy, buffer, shuffle

I've been struggling with finding a good name for this question, and so a good answer to it (that probably already exists somewhere :/), so I won't mind any renaming ideas.

I'm working with numpy arrays where a row represents data on an object, typically something like `features = [feature0, feature1]`.

When using this array, I'm shuffling it first then using it for learning. 
I grew the need of using the features of the i previous rows in the current one when using it (after shuffling).

To do that, I used a buffer and it resulted in me using a new array with rows like `[featuresN-i, ..., featuresN-1, featuresN]` for row N and then shuffling it.

I am wondering if there is a way to shuffle the index instead and get a 3d array like that from a something_function on my 2d array:

```
original_array.something_function(shuffled_index[N:M]) 
-> [
    [[features of shuffled_index[ N ] - i],
                   ...                    ,
     [features of shuffled_index[ N ]    ]], 
    [[features of shuffled_index[N+1] - i],
                   ...                    ,
     [features of shuffled_index[N+1]    ]],
                  .....                    ,
    [[features of shuffled_index[ M ] - i],
                   ...                    ,
     [features of shuffled_index[ M ]    ]]
   ]
```

And if there is, will it be worth calling it to reduce the size of my buffered array by a factor i ?

Any hints are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you realized yourself: don't shuffle the array. Shuffle the indices.

```
import numpy as np

# create data
nrows = 100
ncols = 4
arr = np.random.rand(nrows, ncols)

# create indices and shuffle
indices = np.arange(nrows)
np.random.shuffle(indices) # in-place operation!

# loop over shuffled indices, do stuff with array
for ii in indices:
    print ii, arr[[ii-1, ii, (ii+1) % nrows]] # (ii+1) % nrows to handle edge case (through wrap around)
```